# Refreshing css that applies to a element property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a check box that has some CSS code to make it look like the Android checkbox.

The css is styled to apply the changes when a property .

```
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    background: inherit;
    left: 20px;
}
```

When the page loads i do this

```
$(function() {

    var autoPopulateForm = {{ $settings['company_send_input_form_prompt'] }};
    document.getElementById('autoPopulateForm').checked = true;
```

This changes the state of the attribute but the CSS graphics does not reflect the change.

How can I remedy this, is there away to refresh the item or somethings that accomplishes the same end?

Comment: What is `autoPopulateForm`? Is the checkbox id?

Comment: Which browser are you trying to achieve this in? Styling checkboxes and other default form UI elements is not very easy, and a lot of people resort to  implementing their own 'fake' versions to ensure a common experience across each browser.

Comment: @David Rosa yeah var autoPopulateForm is the boolean state it should be and #autoPopulateForm is the id of the checkbox itself. I should change that wording mind like

Comment: @toomanyredirects  I'm using a boot strap snipt so the styling is not a issue for me, tweaking it to get it work with javascript and my backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working like a charm! The only guess I could make would be that you did not check the conditions every time. Look at the fiddle I made to get the whole Idea that UI can be toggled easily.

HTML

```
<div class="material-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="autoPopulateForm">
  <label for="autoPopulateForm">Label</label>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var autoPopulateForm;
toggle();
function toggle() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (autoPopulateForm == 1) {
            console.log('a');
            autoPopulateForm = 0;
        }
        else {
            console.log('b');
            autoPopulateForm = 1;
        }
        if (autoPopulateForm == 1) {
            document.getElementById('autoPopulateForm').checked = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('autoPopulateForm').checked = false;
        }
    }, 400);
}
```

CSS

```
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 0.5;
    conetnt: "";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  background: inherit;
  left: 20px;
    conetnt: "";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

### [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veawor2v/)